# T-Feedback Circuit Vo/Vi (Why is my approach wrong)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, gain, differential-amplifier

[image]

Here's what I did. I know it's wrong but I cannot figure out why.

Let \$V_s\$ be the voltage at the node between R2, R3 and R4.

From the ground to \$V_o\$ terminal there is a voltage \$V_o\$ which
is divided over R3 and R4 in such a manner: \$V_s=\frac{V_o R4}{R3+R4}\$

Is this correct?

From the ground to \$V_i\$ terminal there is a voltage \$-V_i\$ which
is divided over R1, R2 and R4 in such a manner: \$V_s=\frac{-V_i R4}{R1+R2+R4}\$

Is this correct?

Now equating the above two equations one gets the wrong answer for \$\frac{V_o}{V_i}\$. The correct approach uses a Thevenin simplification.

I understand the Thevenin approach but what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: R1 and R2 and R4  don't form a simple passive voltage divider, because the opamp will force the "virtual ground" node to, well, ground. Hence, the name.

Comment: Both voltage divider equations are wrong. In the first, because R2//R4; and you can't apply the voltage divider in the 2nd because R3 is also connected to the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct?

No, because Vs must include R2 as a factor i.e.

\$V_s = V_o\cdot \dfrac{R_2 || R_4}{R_2 || R_4 + R_3}\$

Where R2||R4 is the parallel resistance of those resistors.

> Is this correct?

No because voltage Vi appears exclusively across R1 and hence sets the current into R2. This is because Vin- is a virtual earth.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it:

You can simplify to the basic inverting opamp equation, Vo = -Vi*(Rf/Ri).

Since your R4 goes to ground, and the other end of R2 goes to ground as well, those two resistors are in parallel (as noted above), then your Rf = (R2||R4 + R3) and Ri = R1